# Ocaml type Error in return statement of recursive function

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have a handwritten predictive parser. 
Each nonterminal has a corresponding parse method.Each parser method is of type tokenlist -> tokenlist * Ast`

Inside each method, I use the convention "tokenlist_symbol" to connote the tokenlist after consuming a specific symbol. In this line: `let typ tokenlist_typ = parseTyp tokenlist in match tokenlist.head with`, typ is an AST and tokenlist_typ is the remainder of the tokenlist after parseTyp has consumed the typ prefix.

However, I am getting `This expression has type 'a -> token_list * Ast.typ
       but an expression was expected of type Ast.typ` error for line, `(Ast.Declaration(typ, identifier, decls_prime), tokenlist_decls_prime)`

```
type token_list = 
  {head : Lexer.token; (** head token. *)
   lexbuf : Lexer.token list}  (** lexer buffer. *)
(** Represents a parser buffer used during parsing of various productions. *)

let default_tokenlist s = {head = Lexer.EOF; lexbuf = Lexer.tokenize s}
(* Create a default [parse_buffer] with the given string [s]. *)

let next tokenlist =
    let {head = _; lexbuf = buf} = tokenlist in
    {head = List.hd buf; lexbuf = List.tl buf}
(** Retrieves a new parser buffer with the next lookahead token. *)

let parseTyp tokenlist = 
    match tokenlist.head with 
    | Lexer.Int -> (next tokenlist, Ast.Int) 
    | Lexer.Bool -> (next tokenlist, Ast.Bool)
    | Lexer.Void -> (next tokenlist, Ast.Void)  
    | Lexer.EOF -> (tokenlist, Ast.Epsilon)
    | _-> let err_msg = "Syntax Error" in
          raise (Syntax_error err_msg)

(*decls = typ “id” decls_prime | epsilon *)
let rec parseDecls tokenlist = 
    let (tokenlist_typ, typ, ) = parseTyp tokenlist in 
        match tokenlist.head with 
        | Lexer.ID identifier -> let (tokenlist_decls_prime, decls_prime) = next tokenlist |> parseDeclsPrime in 
                                (tokenlist_decls_prime, Ast.Declaration(typ, identifier, decls_prime))
        | Lexer.EOF -> (tokenlist, [])
        | _-> let err_msg = Printf.sprintf "Syntax Error" in
              raise (Syntax_error err_msg)

(* decls_prime = vdecl decls | fdecl decls *)
and parseDeclsPrime tokenlist =
    match tokenlist.head with 
    | Lexer.Semicolon -> let tokenlist_vdecl) = next tokenlist in
                let (tokenlist_decls, decls) = parseDecls tokenlist_vdecl in 
                (tokenlist_decls, Ast.DeclsPrime(Lexer.Semicolon, vdecl, decls)) 
    | Lexer.LeftParens -> let (tokenlist_fdecl, fdecl) = next tokenlist |> parseFdecl in 
                let (tokenlist_decls, decls) = parseDecls tokenlist_fdecl in 
                (tokenlist_decls, Ast.DeclsPrime(Lexer.Semicolon, fdecl, decls)) 
    | _-> let err_msg = Printf.sprintf "Syntax Error" in
          raise (Syntax_error err_msg)
```

Comment: @melpomene good catch! type error

Comment: I see code like this `let decls tokenlist_decls = <expr>` when what I think you want is `let (decls, tokenlist_decls) = <expr>`. The former is a function declaration, and it leaves tokenlist_decls undefined. Since you don't mention any undefined identifiers I suspect the code above is not the same code that's getting your reported error.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I'm glad you caught that - however even after changing all `let x_1 x_2 = expr` to `let (x_, x_2) = expr` I get the same error on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
let (decls_prime, tokenlist_decls_prime) = 
    next tokenlist |> parseDeclsPrime
```

Judging by the names, this looks like `parseDeclsPrime` returns the type `Ast * tokenlist`. But it seems to me the parse functions are supposed to return `tokenlist * Ast`.

Most likely the two names in the pair are reversed.

Comment: I can make this change - but compilation error is that it expects "Ast" (not `Ast * tokenlist` or `tokenlist * Ast`)

Comment: It will report the first type mismatch it sees.

Comment: Make sure to try the new code. You changed the meaning of both names if you switched them. This is not just a cosmetic change.